# Python exception handling class - Getting as much details printed

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-2.x, error-handling, exception

I'm trying to write a Exception Handling class in Python so that I can re-use.  If you have any ideas on how I can improve this to output more detailed information I would appreciate it:

```
class EHandle:
    @staticmethod
    def printit():
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
        frm = inspect.trace()[-1]
        mod = inspect.getmodule(frm[0])
        modname = mod.__name__ if mod else frm[1]
        print 'Thrown from', modname
```

And I call the class and method like below:

```
try:
    ggg()
    runafunction()
except:
    EHandle.printit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: The traceback itself holds a lot of information.  You can print it with [`traceback.print_exc()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's built-in exception traceback gives us:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/code/python/error.py", line 43, in <module>
    error()
  File "D:/code/python/error.py", line 28, in error
    another_level()
  File "D:/code/python/error.py", line 31, in another_level
    return tuple()[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Where your code gives us:

```
(<type 'exceptions.IndexError'>, 'error.py', 39)
Thrown from __main__
```

So yours is sparse from the go.
But what makes it bad is line 39 is where I call `error()`.
It's not where the error happens, that's line 31.
It also doesn't give us the path to the file, if I have multiple files with the same name then your program is going to cause me some serious headaches.
And finally the error doesn't throw in `__main__` it throws in `another_level`.

If you are ok with printing the exact same as Python then, as zondo said, you can just change your code to:

```
def printit():
    traceback.print_exc()
```

As you probably want to format it yourself, and be able to change the data. You should use `sys.exc_info()` and `traceback.extract_tb(exc_traceback)`.
And so if you wanted to implement `print_exc` yourself you can use:

```
def print_exc():
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    print 'Traceback (most recent call last):'
    print '\n'.join([
        '  File "{}", line {}, in {}\n    {}'.format(*level)
        for level in traceback.extract_tb(exc_traceback)])
    print '{}: {}\n'.format(exc_type.__name__, exc_value)
```

This allows you to format the error however you want.